# Technical things about conversion from []byte and string in Golang

Tags: memory-management, go, type-conversion

Is it true that converting from `string` to `[]byte` allocates new memory? Also, does converting from `[]byte` to `string` allocates new memory?

```
 s := "a very long string"
 b := []byte(s) // does this doubled the memory requirement?

 b := []byte{1,2,3,4,5, ...very long bytes..}
 s := string(b) // does this doubled the memory requirement?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes in both cases.

[String types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types) are immutable. Therefore converting them to a mutable [slice type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) will allocate a new slice. See also http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

The same with the inverse. Otherwise mutating the slice would change the string, which would contradict the spec.